# namespace pasted to the profile tag of an xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I have a python script that opens an .xml looking for a keyword (entered by the user) that contains the tag `<id>` and returns a fragment of the .xml delimited by the opening and closing of the `<profile></profile>`. The script works well but the problem arises with the "namespaces" of the .xml since although I have managed to solve most of the problem with these spaces so that the search can be carried out (before it was not possible) a "namespace" appears stuck to me to the `<profile>` tag in the result that I can't remove or hide no matter how hard I try...

This is the output I get with the "namespace" attached to the "profile" tag(`<profile xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">`) instead of displaying the normal label(`<profile>`):

```
<profile xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">        
<id>USA-1</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>USA-p1</profile>
    <showtitle>USA1_s1</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.5</ip>
    <port>00005</port>
    <persistencePort>00055</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_5</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T5</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
</profile>


<profile xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">        
<id>USA-2</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>USA-p2</profile>
    <showtitle>USA1_s2</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.6</ip>
    <port>00006</port>
    <persistencePort>00066</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_6</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T6</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
```

this is the code of the python script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET.register_namespace('', "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0")

ns = {'apache':'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'}


print('')
keyword_search = input("Enter the keyword to search: ")
print("--------------------------------------")
print('')

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")

for profile in tree.findall("*/apache:profile", ns):
id = profile.find("apache:id", ns).text
if keyword_search in id:
    
    print(ET.tostring(profile).decode())
```

and this is the .xml I'm using with the "namespaces" included:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">


<profiles>

<profile>
<id>Azerbaiyan-1</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>Azerbaiyan-p1</profile>
    <showtitle>Azerbaiyan_s1</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.1</ip>
    <port>00001</port>
    <persistencePort>00011</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_1</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T1</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>Azerbaiyan-2</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>Azerbaiyan-p2</profile>
    <showtitle>Azerbaiyan_s2</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.2</ip>
    <port>00002</port>
    <persistencePort>00022</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_2</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T2</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>Georgia-1</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>Georgia-p1</profile>
    <showtitle>Georgia_s1</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.3</ip>
    <port>00003</port>
    <persistencePort>00033</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_3</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T3</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
</profile>
<profile>
<id>Georgia-2</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>Georgia-p2</profile>
    <showtitle>Georgia_s2</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.4</ip>
    <port>00004</port>
    <persistencePort>00044</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_4</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T4</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>USA-1</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>USA-p1</profile>
    <showtitle>USA1_s1</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.5</ip>
    <port>00005</port>
    <persistencePort>00055</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_5</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T5</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>USA-2</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>USA-p2</profile>
    <showtitle>USA1_s2</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.6</ip>
    <port>00006</port>
    <persistencePort>00066</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_6</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T6</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
</profile>

</profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Why is the namespace "problematic"?

Comment: I was not referring to the namespaces themselves, I was referring to these as a problem that affects me in the result of the code

Comment: I just edited the sentence to make it better understood, thanks

Comment: How does the problem affect you? Why does it matter? The input XML document defines a default namespace. That means that you will get a namespace also in the output.

Comment: The problem is that I need the fragment that I get as a result to appear exactly the same as it is in the xml, that is, I don't care that the namespace appears in the resulting .xml, what I do care about is that it does so inside the tag `<profile>`. I need to be able to see the tree fragment as it is in the source file.